# Tab focus not working when using GridColumn.CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am creating a data entry WPF `DataGrid` dynamically based on data model details coming from a service. One of these things I do is to define combo boxes which the user can select from e.g. country

I am programatically defining a `DataTemplate` and setting it to the `GridColumn.CellTemplate`

```
colToAdd = new GridColumn
{
    FieldName = field.name,
    Binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("Order.OrderData[{0}]", field.name)), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay },
    Header = GridCreationHelper.GenerateColumnHeader(field), 
    HeaderToolTip = string.Format("Order - {0}", myTI.ToTitleCase(field.name.ExpandTitleCaseToWords())),
    VisibleIndex = colIndex,
    AllowEditing = DefaultBoolean.True,
    AllowGrouping = DefaultBoolean.True,
    CellTemplate = GridCreationHelper.GenerateComboBoxDataTemplate(ViewModel.SelectedOrderType, field.name, View.Name, ViewModel.ComboBoxValues[ViewModel.SelectedOrderType][field.name].Count),
    HeaderStyle = GridCreationHelper.IsFieldMandatory(field) ? View.Resources["OrderEntryMandatoryHeaderStyle"] as Style : null,
    AllowFocus = true
};
```

With the actual DataTemplate defined as follows:

```
public static DataTemplate GenerateComboBoxDataTemplate(OrderType orderType, string columnName, string viewName, int comboBoxCount)
    {
        string selectedIndexMarkup = comboBoxCount == 1 ? " SelectedIndex=\"0\"" : string.Empty;

        string markup =
            string.Format(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                xmlns:dxe=""http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"" xmlns:Key=""ComboBoxEditDataTemplate"">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit xmlns:Name=""PART_Editor"" IsTabStop=""True"" Focusable=""True"" ImmediatePopup=""True"" IsTextEditable=""False"" SelectAllOnGotFocus=""True""
                              ItemsSource=""{{Binding Path=ViewModel.ComboBoxValues[{0}][{1}], ElementName={2}}}"" SelectedItem=""{{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Order.OrderData[{1}]}}""{3} />
        </DataTemplate>", orderType, columnName, viewName, selectedIndexMarkup);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(markup);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
    }
```

This works as expected, but when tabbing through the row, the keyboard focus never gets set into the combo boxes defined as above. To be able to select a drop down, I need to use the mouse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user1892538 Not sure why your answer was deleted or who deleted it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was not ok for you... did it work? Just in case, pls accept it so that others can know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to [an old issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B205403) of DevExpress:

> We have found out that the issue occurs because the IsTabStop property
>   is set to True in your code. As you probably know, our editors are
>   composite controls, containing the standard TextBox control inside. To
>   support keyboard navigation, we set the IsTabStop property for the
>   "outer" control to False once the editor receives keyboard focus, to
>   move focus to the "inner" control (TextBox). The following trigger is
>   used for this purpose:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:BaseEdit}">
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
</Style>
```

And the suggestion from their forum is

> We have not found an acceptable way to fix this at the level of our
>   controls. It appears that the only solution we can suggest is not to
>   set the IsTabStop property value to True (it is True by default). I am
>   attaching a modified project, containing the necessary changes.

You can download the DXSample.zip from that post to see more details.